# Prevent auto-update from closing applications

Tags: software-update

I use a Macbook Pro at work that is running

`macOS Sierra 10.12.2`

I tend to leave a lot of programs running when I leave for the day; Crome, IDEs, Word Docs, etc...

Sometimes when I logon in the morning, I'll have a message saying

> Updates not installed. Some updates could not be installed automatically

The problem is that when it was trying to automatically install the updates, it closed a number of my applications. Not a huge deal because I didn't lose any data but an annoyance because sometimes I leave stuff up to remind me where I left off last night.

I don't want to disable automatic updates entirely, is there an option to somehow leave auto-updates on but not try to force close open applications?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but a work around may be to always (or regularly) check for updates before you leave and make sure it successfully finishes the shutdown process before leaving. If it successfully quits all the applications it will restore them as long as you have "Restore windows when logging back in" is checked. The problem is when one of the applications refuses to quit.

Comment: ^ (also turn off auto-updates if you use that workaround)